# How can I move object keys

Tags: javascript, lodash, javascript-objects

Let me create an object as below:

```
let refs = {
  'key1': {name: 'one'},
  'key2': {name: 'two'},
  'key3': {name: 'three'}
};
```

I want to **reorder** keys.
For example: moving 'key2' to the last.
How can I do this?

I have tried the following solution, but it doesn't effect.

```
let temp = refs['key2'];
delete refs['key2'];
let refsCloned = _.clone(refs);
refsCloned['key2'] = temp;
```

[JsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jgw74pLa/1/)

Comment: JavaScript does not guarantee the order of object keys. Therefore it makes no sense to "order" the keys.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: Use a `Map` instead if you want it to respect order, Object doesn't guaranty order

Comment: Javascript **does** in many cases guarantee a certain order for properties, which is however only manually changeable for the "in creation order" part, where i will not go into much detail, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/6692606) for more info. It is **not a good idea** to rely on this order, a more fit data structure should be taken.

Comment: To do this, we must rewrite the "memory manager" of all JavaScript interpreters, while this feature does not bring any interest or benefit

Comment: @MisterJojo *some* environments actually do this. [To some extent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties). There is some order introduced but not *all* environments conform to the spec and the spec might be a bit unintuitive in some respects. So it's still best not to rely on iteration order of keys in objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let refs = {
      'key1': {name: 'one'},
      'key2': {name: 'two'},
      'key3': {name: 'three'}
    };
delete refs['key2'];
const newObj = {}
newObj.key2 = {name: 'two'}
const resultObj = {...refs, ...newObj}

console.log(resultObj)
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: @MisterJojo What is the relation that css? What is it doing?

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake, no need for css there

Comment: @Arvindyadav : Use as-console-wrapper to maximize console information area, to make it more readable. this not about your code, this is about SO snippet.

Comment: @KemalDuran : Use as-console-wrapper to maximize console information area, to make it more readable. this not about your code, this is about SO snippet.